# PHP DOTNET Interop with C# Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, php, com, interop

Is it possible to have PHP interact with a running C# Windows Form Application?

I've created COM Exposed DLLs before and called them from PHP using the DOTNET object but it didn't seem to work for me with a "Windows Form Application". Do I need to make the COM DLL and have it somehow interact with the Windows Form Application?

**Edit:**

I decided to write a quick EXE in .NET3.5 Client Framework and see if the methods are available to PHP then. It appears that I am run Methods now, bizzare! I guess its only possible with v3.5 Client and not v4.5.

This is the C# and PHP Code:

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Example.Interop.FormText
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public int Minus(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $app = new DOTNET("Example.Interop.FormText", "Example.Interop.FormText.Form1");
    echo $app->Minus(19, 20);
?>
```

I haven't Tested to see if I can run a Function that Interacts with the UI though. Will test it next, but unfortunately I don't think I can fallback on v3.5 for this project.

Comment: Can you modify the windows form application to expose some REST or HTTP SOAP services internally? If you have access to that this could become a lot easier.

Comment: To be honest I was trying for a quick win, rather than having to code some kind of Server and Authentication. As I'd said, I've successfully run Methods from C# .net3.5 DLLs using the DOTNET as long as the DLL has COM-Visible turned on. From PHP its like 1 line of code, not sure why I can't do it with an EXE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is this:

#### Out-Of-Process Com Component

I actually did this with a VB6 program 15 years ago and it worked perfectly like you say! It had a main form, I hit it from an ASP 3.0 site. It had the guts of the site's app in it and served as an admin, but I had no problem updating the UI either as COM methods fired.

Description From the link below (this answer is useless without it due to the complexity of the problem; the link includes a download sample app. Maybe you can google this text if the link dies).

*In Microsoft Windows operating systems, the Microsoft COM technology enables software components communicate with other software components. You can use Microsoft COM technology to create reusable software components. You can also develop applications by linking these components together and take advantage of Windows services.

Out-of-process server objects are implemented in an executable file and are run in a separate process space.*

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977996

Comment: It has taken me a while to follow, but I believe this is the answer to my initial question. I'm not sure how I'd implement it, but I guess thats another question. Thanks!